# Factory reset Microsoft Surface pro 4

Tags: reset, factory-defaults, microsoft-surface-pro-4

My friend says his surface pro 4 was hacked and wants me to do a factory reset for him. I found this on youtube and it looks pretty easy. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5CwczBa1Mk

My questions are:

1. Where is the recovery image kept?
2. Is it possible that could have been compromised?
3. Can I download a trusted image?